# How to find uncommon lines between two text files using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, analytics

I have two text files file1.txt & file2.txt

file1.txt Contains :

```
                 a
                 b
                 c
```

file2.txt Contains :

```
                 a
                 b
                 c
                 d
                 e 
                 f
```

The Output Should be :

```
                  d
                  e
                  f
```

The command i'm trying to use is 'diff file2.txt file1.txt' 
It gives the common lines only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the input files *are* sorted:

```
join -v 2 file1.txt file2.txt
```

Check [`man join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) for details on all the other things `join` can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

please try below ones

```
grep -vf file1.txt file2.txt

comm -13 file1.txt file2.txt
```

for diff you have to perform something extra

```
diff inp inp1 | grep '>' | cut -f2 -d' '
```